# Determining if a Java.awt.Rectangle contains a Java.awt.Color

Tags: java

I was wondering how I would determine if a Java.awt.Rectangle contains a pixel that is a specific Java.awt.Color. I've been searching all over but I cannot find any information on this or if it's even possible.

So I was wondering how to determine if a Rectangle contains a a pixel with a specific Color or if a specific colored pixel is inside a defined Rectangle.

Example: The left image is a black rectangle. Lets say I have a defined Java.awt.Color that is red. I want to determine if that rectangle contains a pixel that is that color.
[image]

Comment: rectangle hasn't a color.color is set for graphic

Comment: The question, in the current form, does not make sense. A `Rectangle` is an abstract thing, consisting of (x,y,width,height). It does not contain any "color", and the concept of "color" is unrelated to that. Presumably, you're looking for a way to detect whether a certain *area on the screen* contains a pixel with the given color. You should explain in more detail what you *actually* want to achieve.

Comment: It appears to be an XY Problem type question.

Comment: Sorry, I made my post more clear and concise.

Comment: Going to need some more information about the use case. How will the pixel get there? Is it possible for you to store the coordinates of the pixel when it is created? Then the problem becomes quite easy. Otherwise, if you're talking about using some machine vision techniques to recognize color in a region, the answer may be a bit more involved.

Comment: Where is the pixel painted? On the desktop? A window of any application running in your OS? A browser window? A `Component` in the same Java application? AWT? Swing? JavaFX? ???

Comment: The pixel isn't defined, I just want to be able to tell if a Java.awt.Rectangle contains a specific color if that makes sense? So for example I have that rectangle above, I want to be able to tell if that rectangle contains the color red or a defined color. And to do that I guess I need to see if it contains a pixel with that color?

Comment: *I just want to be able to tell if a Java.awt.Rectangle contains a specific color if that makes sense?*  That's the point people are trying to make.  Your question **makes no sense**.  A Rectangle is an abstract object with a position, width, and height.  **A Rectangle contains no color whatsoever.**  It's only when a Rectangle is drawn using a Graphics object that a color is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to find out if some pixel on a Graphics was painted in this color, you can only discover it if the Graphics was created over a BufferedImage. So you could run the same code that draws on screen, say call a Component's paint(Graphics) method, passing to it the result of BufferedImage.createGraphics() call. Once painting is done, check pixel values in the range you need by calling BufferedImage.getRGB(x, y).